# tomcat in eclipse, when shutdown, there is a mistake

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

when I shut down the `tomcat(v9.0) in eclipse(2018-12) in Mac`, there is a mistake said that there is a mistake on the port, just

```
"SEVERE: Failed to destroy component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler destroy failed."
```

However, when I start up and shut down by using the command line, there is no mistake, and when I start up tomcat in eclipse, there is also no mistake.

[image]

Comment: bug raised for this... please check here https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62657

Comment: I had seen that website, I met the same question as that, I do not think the mistakes in the mac os, the configuration of mine computer is as same as the second answer.